# How to fire mouse wheel event in Firefox with JavaScript using groovy and webdriver?

Tags: selenium, groovy, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know how to fire a mouse-wheel event using Web-driver and groovy. I have enclosed the code for which I want to be able to scroll down 100 pix, can anyone show code that would be able to do that?

```
package Check
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

class Fourth {
    //FirefoxDriver driver;

    static main(args) {
        def FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dreams")
        //Code to allow web page to be scrolled needs to be inserted here
        sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to scroll down the page using the JavaScript executor, I have posted the code as it relates to groovy, enjoy!

```
package Check
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

class Fourth {
    //FirefoxDriver driver;

    static main(args) {
        def FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dreams")
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,2000);");
                        sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
        }

}
```